# enabled and disabled text input on checkbox checked and unchecked

Tags: javascript

i've checkbox and text input

What I need is to enable text input when i check the checkbox and to disable text input when i uncheck the checkbox

I'm using the following code but it do the reverse enable when unchecked / disable when checked so how to adjust it fit with my needs.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="yourBox">
<input type="text" id="yourText">
<script>
document.getElementById('yourBox').onchange = function() {
document.getElementById('yourText').enabled = this.checked;
};
</script>
```

any help ~ thanks

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You just need to add a `!` in front of `this.checked`.

Here's an example that shows the change:

```js
document.getElementById('yourBox').onchange = function() {
    document.getElementById('yourText').disabled = !this.checked;
};
```

```html
<input type="text" id="yourText" disabled />
<input type="checkbox" id="yourBox" />
```

Comment: You should also trigger this onload or add the correct default properties in the markup.

Comment: In most circumstances you may also want to add the following line to clear the text area if the user unchecks the box after having entered text already: `document.getElementById('yourText').value = ''`

Comment: and also make an entry in the textbox required if the checkbox is checked: `document.getElementById('yourText').required = this.checked;`

Comment: I have tons of `input` and `select` which needs to be enabled or disabled with their respective checkbox, is there any way to write shorter code for this?

Comment: When I this this I get Property 'checked' does not exist on type 'GlobalEventHandlers'

Answer (score 4):

A jQuery solution could be this one:

```
<script>
$('#yourBox').change(function() {
    $('yourText').attr('disabled',!this.checked)
});
</script>
```

It is the same as Minko's answer but I find it more elegant.

Comment: Note that in jQuery, one should use `prop`, not `attr` to set the value of Boolean attributes.

Answer (score 2):

Try it. If you use a label then add onmousedown to it

```html
<form >
  <input type="text" id="yourText" disabled />
<input type="checkbox" id="yourBox" onmousedown="this.form.yourText.disabled=this.checked"/>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

A better solution could be:

```js
var checkbox = document.querySelector("#yourBox");
var input = document.querySelector("#yourText");

var toogleInput = function(e){
  input.disabled = !e.target.checked;
};

toogleInput({target: checkbox});
checkbox.addEventListener("change", toogleInput);
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="yourBox">
<input type="text" id="yourText">
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
function createInput( chck ) {
    if( jQuery(chck).is(':checked') ) {
        jQuery('<input>', {
            type:"text",
            "name":"meta_enter[]",
            "class":"meta_enter"
        }).appendTo('p.checkable_options');
    }
    else {
        jQuery("input.meta_enter").attr('disabled','disabled');
    }        
}
createInput( chck );
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="checkable" class="checkable" value="3" />
<input type="radio" name="checkable" class="checkable" value="4" onclick="createInput(this)" />
```

Comment: Note that in jQuery, one should use `prop`, not `attr` to set the value of Boolean attributes.