# Javascript position of onchange assignment

Tags: javascript, checkbox, onchange

I have a checkbox and a text input. I want that the text input is only enabled if the checkbox is checked. I found an answer to this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15140237/enabled-and-disabled-text-input-on-checkbox-checked-and-unchecked), but the following code did not work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>title</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      document.getElementById('yourBox').onchange = function() {
        document.getElementById('yourText').disabled = !this.checked;
      };
    </script>
  </head>
    <body>
         <input type="text" id="yourText" disabled /> 
         <input type="checkbox" id="yourBox" />
    </body>
</html>
```

However, I noticed that the code works if I move the < script > environment below the < input > boxes like that

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>title</title>
      </head>
        <body>
             <input type="text" id="yourText" disabled /> 
             <input type="checkbox" id="yourBox" />
         <script type="text/javascript">
          document.getElementById('yourBox').onchange = function() {
            document.getElementById('yourText').disabled = !this.checked;
          };
        </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Why does the position of the < script > environment play a role for the onchange attribute?

Comment: Browsers read like us, from the top left, to the right and down. Your javascript is causing an error because the browser hasn't read your element to know it exists.  `window.onload`  will fix your issue as the source code will only be called/used after the page has loaded.

Answer (score 2):

That's because the page is parsed from the top, and each element is added as soon as it is parsed.

When the `script` tag has been parsed the code will run right away. At that time the `input` tags hasn't been parsed, so the `input` elements doesn't exist yet.

By placing the `script` tag below the `input` tags, the script runs after the `input` elements has been created.

Instead of rearranging the code, you can use the `onload` event to make sure that the code runs after the page is completely parsed:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>title</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById('yourBox').onchange = function() {
          document.getElementById('yourText').disabled = !this.checked;
        };
      };
    </script>
  </head>
    <body>
         <input type="text" id="yourText" disabled /> 
         <input type="checkbox" id="yourBox" />
    </body>
</html>
```