# How to display text when check-box is checked in EXT JS 3.3

Tags: javascript, extjs, checkbox, extjs3

In Ext JS 3.3, I've a requirement that when a checkbox is checked, a text message has to be displayed to the right of it and when it's unchecked, the text message shouldn't be displayed.

Also, I'm using 'ref' attribute for identifying the checkbox due to other reasons. the working condition at present for checkbox checking is ( this.checkbox.checked )
 Appreciate any help, Thanks in advance.

This is similar in context to [enabled-and-disabled-text-input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15140237/enabled-and-disabled-text-input-on-checkbox-checked-and-unchecked/32244742#32244742)

Comment: Can't you just add into the "check" event of the checkbox : if (value) displayMessage (); ? You would have to declare a label next to your checkbox and get it hidden or show into displayMessage()

Comment: is it by using listeners: change function() (or) directly have a condition of if(this.checkbox.checked) below the checkbox creation ?

Comment: Inside the listeners