# Enabling/Disabling inputs based on checkbox activity

Tags: javascript, html

Please note, I have referred to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15140254/6464893) and my solution is currently using that approach.

Here is my HTML:

```
<head>
<script>

document.getElementById('average_price').onchange = function() {
    document.getElementById('average_price_symbol').disabled = !this.checked;

};

</script>
</head>

<center>
<form action="/custom" method="POST">
    <h2>Generate Custom Report</h2>
        <br>

        <input type="checkbox" id="average_price" name="average_price"> <b>Average Price</b>
        <br>
        <input type="text" id="average_price_symbol" name="average_price_symbol" placeholder="symbol" disabled>
        <br>

        <input type="submit" value="RUN">
</form>

</center>
```

When the form loads, the text field is disabled, however, the checkbox does not change the state of the field. I'm not exactly sure what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script executes before your HTML loads, so this doesn't find anything:

```
document.getElementById('average_price')
```

Move the script to the bottom of the page, traditionally just inside the `</body>` tag.

Comment: Thanks for this!

Answer (score 0):

Disable your input programatically

Reminder: ALWAYS put your scripts before the closing body tag

HTML

```
<h2>Generate Custom Report</h2>
  <br>
  <input type="checkbox" id="average_price" name="average_price"> <b>Average Price</b>
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="average_price_symbol" name="average_price_symbol" placeholder="symbol" >
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="RUN">
```

JS

```
var checkbox = document.getElementById('average_price');
var input = document.getElementById('average_price_symbol');

input.disabled = true;
checkbox.addEventListener('change', function (e) {
  console.log('CHECKED', this.checked);
  input.disabled = !this.checked;
  (!input.disabled && input.focus());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the code to a document ready function will help.

```
$('document').ready(function(){ document.getElementById('average_price') });
```